# Proper form for JQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it good practice to chain Ajax calls? I know ajax calls are asynchronous but I have a circumstance where I would like to trigger another ajax call based on the success or error of the first call. The code looks something like this...

```
$.ajax({
    url:'urlToFile.html', 
    success:function(result){
       $.ajax({
          url:'secondAjaxCall.html', 
          success:function(result){
             alert("past");
          },
          error: function(result) {
             alert("no connection");
          }
       });
    },
    error: function(result) {
       alert("no connection");
    }
});
```

Comment: I will be sure to do this. I've been very thankful for all the help I've gotten here. It took me a few posts to understand the workflow and points system.

Comment: Nice - 100% now. Thanks for the accept on this one too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that. If you have a lot of that going on, it might be worth looking into a control-flow library, just to keep your code free of the "pyramid effect" caused by nested asynchronous callbacks - but two levels deep or so is still pretty easy to reason about.

Comment: Is this what you're referring to for control flow library? http://dailyjs.com/2011/11/14/popular-control-flow/

Comment: Exactly. In fact I've used [this one](https://github.com/caolan/async) on many occasions (although in node.js - it's supposed to work in the browser as well though). But again, I don't think you need to bring in any more dependencies for your situation. The goal is to make your code easier to reason about, and what you posted still looks pretty manageable and straight forward to me.